# How to validate JWT token for Microsoft Graph API

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, vert.x

I have a web application with a vert.x (4.4.2) backend and my goal is to use Azure AD to authenticate my users and obtain JWT token to call Microsft Graph API from the application.

Today, I am using oAuth2 CODE flow (vert.x OAuth2 client) in this way:

1. The application initiate authentication by calling HTTTP authenticate endpoint on our backend
2. backend redirects the user to SSO
3. SSO post CODE to backend
4. Backend call HTTP endpoint of SSO to get tokens
5. Backend validates the token (!!!)
6. Backend redirects to the application with the tokens

This is working perfectly when we are using default scope (clientId/.default) but if we change the scope eg. Team.ReadBasic.All Chat.ReadWrite ChatMessage.Read the token validation fails on the backend side with signature error

```
11:38:26.199 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-15] ERROR io.vertx.ext.web.RoutingContext - Unhandled exception in router
java.lang.RuntimeException: Signature verification failed
    at io.vertx.ext.auth.impl.jose.JWT.decode(JWT.java:312)
    at io.vertx.ext.auth.impl.jose.JWT.decode(JWT.java:177)
```

From other posts, I understood that we should never validate JWT token if it was generated to access the Graph API. So my questions are following:

-> Is it possible to disable the token validation on vert.x side so we can have different scopes

-> If not, what would be the best practice? Use one token with default scope only to access our application and to access Graph API it will be the application itself which will request another token ???

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Graph API is adding extension to the JWT validation (hashed nonce).

So to make it work, we need to set:

```
new OAuth2Options()
    .setJWTOptions(new JWTOptions().setNonceAlgorithm("SHA-256")))
    ...
```

This will ensure that the nonce is replaced with the hashed value and correclty validated.